# Como sumar o multiplicar las diagonales de una matriz en pseudocodigo

Tags: pseudocódigo

necesito recorrer la matriz de forma diagonal.

Algoritmo Final

```
Definir N , Suma, Contador , F, C Como Entero 
Suma=0
Contador= 0
Escribir "Ingresar la dimension de la matriz"
Leer N
Mientras N<= 0 Hacer  
    Escribir "El numero no puede ser menor o igual a 0"
    Leer N
Fin Mientras    
Dimension A(N,N) 
Para F<-1 Hasta N Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para C<-1 Hasta N Con Paso 1 Hacer      
            A(F,C) = Contador
            Contador = Contador + 1 
    Fin Para
Fin Para

Para F<-1 Hasta N Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para C<-1 Hasta N Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir Sin Saltar A(F,C)," "
    Fin Para
    Escribir " "
Fin Para
//Imprimimos la suma
Escribir " La suma de las diagonales es " 
Para F<-1 Hasta N Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para C<-1 Hasta N Con Paso 1 Hacer
        
    Fin Para
    Escribir " "
Fin Para
```

FinAlgoritmo

No logro comprender como recorrer la matriz de forma diagonal para realizar la respectiva multiplicacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las preguntas que solo exponen enunciados de ejercicios sin mayor evidencia de trabajo previo por parte de quien publica no son bien vistas y terminan cerradas. Lee por favor  [ask]

Comment: Guíate por la indicación en el enunciado. Tienes que ir recorriendo esa primera columna de arriba a abajo. Para cada elemento, comienzas de su posición `[0, j]` y luego te desplazas uno hacia arriba y uno hacia la derecha, validando de no irte más allá de la fila `0` o de la columna `N-1` (pensando que tu matriz tiene N columnas)

Comment: @Alfabravo Comprendo la logica, mas no comprendo como plasmarlo en codigo

Comment: Tienes tres ciclos `para` implementados en tu pseudocódigo. Inténtalo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pensa en funcion de que valores de las filas y las columnas, la primera la obtenes cuando columnas y filas valen lo mismo i=j [0,0] [1,1] [2,2] etc.....
La otra diagonal es un poco mas complicada pero pensala como el valor de la matriz -1, por que ... supone tenes una matriz de 3x3 vos estas sacando la diagonal que ba de arriba a la derecha a abajo a la izquierda .... que valor tiene la matriz en la diagonal superior [0,2] y en el centro [1,1] osea que se podria decir que i+j=2 o lo que es lo mimso filas mas columnas te tienen que sumar 2 y si lo probas abajo [2,0] y ahi tenes tu diagonal.